# bittorrent client within silverlight

Tags: silverlight, sockets, bittorrent

Is it possible to make bittorrent client within silverlight, which will run in browser?

this would be unusual bittorrent client, he will download data from the server and will seed it. is it possible to do?

Is it possible to do within different, web tech, such as e.g. JavaFX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, completely possible. You can't receiving incoming connections, but that's no requirement for Bittorrent. The only thing that makes it difficult is that the peers you are connecting to need to serve a socketpolicy file on port 80 or 943, and almost none of them do. Without this policy, the Siverlight BT client will only work in the trusted 'Out of browser'-mode, which make it less usefull.

It's like a chicken-egg problem: as long as their is no large userbase for a Silverlight BT client, 'normal' nodes will not open port 943, and without that port, there never will be a large userbase for such an client.

Adobe solved this smartly by introducing Cirrus, their hosted rendezvous routing service which makes P2P possible from Flash without torrents.

Answer (score 0):

No. You don't have access to the client's file system outside sandbox access.

http://betaforums.silverlight.net/forums/p/9351/29437.aspx

Comment: It is also not possible to bind to a port using web based tech. Better to make a real application in c#,c++ etc.

Comment: This is not an option. Is it possible to do within different, web tech, such as e.g. JavaFX?

Comment: The only way you can get access to the file system is the temp files, which is really of no use. browsers intentionally sandbox the processes to prevent people from planting viruses. You may be able to create a browser extension, but that would be much more annoying.

Comment: Incorrect. You can invoke a SaveFileAs dialogue, which gives you unrestricted access to a single file. If there are multiple files in the torrent, you can create one big zipfile from memory, and use that as a container.